# Stars and Bars with a maximum number per tuple

Tags: permutations, binomial-coefficients

I have 4-tuples of numbers, each consisting of 1 to 10. How do I find the number of permutations possible to reach a total sum of 21? I tried using the formula given in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient and plotted it against a graph, problem is, my graph should look like an n-shaped graph, but instead, I got an exponential graph instead.

Comment: The coefficient of $x^{21}$ in $(x + x^2 + ... + x^{10})^4$

Comment: Can you explain to me what this formula means?

Comment: It's a generating function -- adding up the number of ways to get a sum under restrictions like this is the same as multiplying together polynomials representing those restrictions and looking at the coefficient corresponding to the sum you're interested in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An approach using generating functions:

In order to count up the number of solutions that sum to $n$, we can look at the coefficient of $x^n$ in the generating function $f(x)$:

$$[x^{n}]f(x) = [x^{n}]\left(\sum_{n=1}^{10}x^n\right)^4$$

The $[x^n]$ operator refers to the coefficient of $x^n$.

Use the identity $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{k}x^n = \frac{1-x^{k+1}}{1-x}$ to convert this expression:

$$[x^{n}]f(x) = [x^{n}]\left(\frac{1-x^{11}}{1-x} - x^0\right)^4 = [x^{n}]\left(\frac{x-x^{11}}{1-x}\right)^4$$

Simplify:

$$[x^{n}]f(x) = [x^{n}]\left(\frac{x^{44} - 4 x^{34} + 6 x^{24} - 4 x^{14} + x^4}{(1-x)^4}\right)$$

Factor out $\dfrac{1}{(1-x)^4}$ and use the identity $\displaystyle \frac{1}{(1-x)^{m+1}} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{n+m}{m}x^n$:

$$[x^{n}]f(x) = [x^{n}]\left(x^{44} - 4 x^{34} + 6 x^{24} - 4 x^{14} + x^4\right)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{n+3}{3}x^n$$

Distribute:

$$[x^{n}]f(x) = [x^{n}]\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{n+3}{3}x^{n+44}-4\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{n+3}{3}x^{n+34}+6\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{n+3}{3}x^{n+24}-4\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{n+3}{3}x^{n+14} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{n+3}{3}x^{n+4}\right)$$

Shift indices:

$$[x^{n}]f(x) = [x^{n}]\left(\sum_{n=44}^{\infty}\binom{n-41}{3}x^{n}-4\sum_{n=34}^{\infty}\binom{n-31}{3}x^{n}+6\sum_{n=24}^{\infty}\binom{n-21}{3}x^{n}-4\sum_{n=14}^{\infty}\binom{n-11}{3}x^{n} + \sum_{n=4}^{\infty}\binom{n-1}{3}x^{n}\right)$$

If we look at the lower bounds of the indices, the smallest $x^n$ that we could get the coefficient for is $x^{4}$. This is because $4$ is the smallest possible value of $n$ under the $x_i$ constraints, which occurs when each value of the tuple is $1$. The coefficients for all $n<4$ are simply $0$.

Now we can invoke the coefficient operator:

$$[x^n]f(x) = \binom{n-41}{3}-4\binom{n-31}{3}+6\binom{n-21}{3}-4\binom{n-11}{3}+\binom{n-1}{3}$$

Set $n=21$ to get the number of solutions to the original problem:

$$[x^{21}]f(x) = 660$$

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, to clear things up, I just need to replace x with my number and keeping the values of (n-41), (n-31) and so on right? sorry, as I've not touched on this topic for almost 7 years and suddenly its needed in my university.

Comment: The $x$-terms are from the polynomials -- their values aren't relevant for the final calculation. The $[x^n]f(x)$ part means "take the coefficient of $x^n$ from the polynomial $f(x)$", so $n$ is what you replace with your number. In your case it comes out to $-4\binom{21-11}{3} + \binom{21-1}{3} = 660$ (the other binomials are $0$)

Comment: Is there a name for the identity involving $\frac{1}{(1-x)^{m+1}}$